# Angular precedence of ng-repeat with filter and ng-if on the same element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If there's a **ng-if** and a **ng-repeat** with a filter on the same element the filter gets called once even if the **ng-if** is hiding the element.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  }, 2000);
});

app.filter('crashyFilter', function() {
  return function(list) {
    return list.map(function(item) {
      return item + 1;
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-if="list" ng-repeat="item in list | crashyFilter">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</body>
```

In the browser console you can see that the map call fails once because the list parameter is undefined. I made a plunker with it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/g4JMfGDHXHYcNSguwirJ?p=preview).

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging about in the angular codebase I found out the reason.

The **[ng-repeat](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/7175d0d0e3021ad015ff8e5791f8585396906b05/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js)** directive has priority 1000 while **[ng-if](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/728f7e2a85397ac684e1b8d3472f0a1f437c3ad9/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js)** has priority 600.

The angular documentation for the [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service states that if directives are set on the same element they are compiled in decreasing priority order, thus **ng-repeat** gets compiled before **ng-if**.

That explains why the the filter would also get called before **ng-if** can disable the element.

Answer (score 2):

[Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) came handy to solve the issue for me[AngularJS].

```
<option ng-repeat="list in lists | filter:{Location:{event: 1}}" value="{{list.Location.id}}">
```

Where i wanted to show element's where event is 1.